# interior clear span 16' header size

Tags: structural

Hi I am looking to clear span 16' interior load on single floor home with light storage in attic. 
The opening now is 12' supported by 2 2 x 10 hemlock with 3/4"cdx glued in as core. Dose this need more support for the extra 4'?
Thanks Ed

Answer (score 2):

If it's a load bearing wall (seems likely), you need an engineer.

Comment: Or if your local inspector takes a look at it you can offer a well oversize solution - if he agrees.  I have done this in place of engineers for simple things like this and the $40 extra for the beam was well offset for the $500 architect plans.  This is all determined by house structure and how good the inspector's ability is.